# MPMediaQuery - getting the songs for each 'section'

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaquery

I am trying to build a media browser on iOS in objective-c.
So far I can get the songsQuery:

```
_query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
```

And in my tableView datasource I can get the number of sections and the section titles like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(_query)
    {
        return _query.itemSections.count;
    }
    
    return 1;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    
    return _query.itemSections[section].title;
}
```

That gives me (say) 26 sections, with titles like "A", "B", "C" and so on... as expected.
What I don't understand is how to get the count of songs in each section. Ie how to get all the songs for sections "A" or "B" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the number of songs in each MPMediaQuery section.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer?language=objc), `MPMediaQuerySection` should include a `range`
property which stores the range of the array of items included in the section. The number of songs may then be obtained by taking the `length` of the range. Like so:

```
NSUInteger numSongs = _query.itemSections[section].range.length;
```

You should also be able to obtain an array of all the songs in the section like this:

```
//The range of the song in the section
NSRange *sectionRange = _query.itemSections[section].range;
//Array of MPMediaItems in the section
NSArray *songsInSection = [_query.items subarrayWithRange: sectionRange];
```

Comment: Thank you - that was eaxactly what I was looking for.